# What's wrong with this function that shortens strings?

Tags: c, string

I have defined a function in C which shortens long strings to fixed size and prints the shortened string. The function goes like this:

```
void fit(char *str,unsigned int size) // shorten long strings to fixed size, "size" and prints the shortened string.
{
    if ( strlen(str) > size)
        str[size] = '\0';  
    printf("%s", str);  // prints the shortened string
}
```

If I run this function, the compilers points out no warning nor error but the execution stops. What part of the code makes the execution stop?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void fit(char *str, unsigned int size);

int main(void)
{
    fit("Hello People!!", 6);
}

void fit(char *str,unsigned int size)
{
    if ( strlen(str) > size)
        str[size] = '\0';
    printf("%s", str);
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c/364/undefined-behavior/6644/modify-string-literal#t=201608100622195552693

Comment: Your are trying to cut a `string literal`, that is `const char *`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In standard C and C++, string literals (`"these"`) are read-only.

Typically these are located in read-only memory. By writing to `str` in your specific example your program attempts write to write-protected memory, which is disallowed by the OS (or the runtime, if applicable) which causes an abnormal program termination. If you were writing C++ the compiler might complain that you were passing a `const char*` to a function that accepted a non-`const` argument.

You have four options:

1. Tell the compiler to put the `"Hello People!!" string in a writable data area instead of write-protected data when building or initializing the program - this would require a compiler or platform-specific feature and is not part of standard C or C++.
2. Use an OS-specific command to make the memory area writable (have fun!)
3. Copy the string to a mutable buffer before you modify it.
4. Use `char str[] = "Hello People!!";` - this is basically the same as option 3 but the compiler does it for you. Be careful when leaving scope, however.

Note that inserting null characters into a string buffer as a means of shortening a string can be a bad idea because it hides the extra space in the allocated buffer. Generally you should treat strings as immutable, and if you want to be efficient by re-using strings in a copy-on-write fashion then use `start/end` pairs that point to an extant buffer instead of relying on null-termination.

Comment: then i guess the solution would be to assign the string to a char array?

Answer (score 2):

You can use your static string to initialize memory that *you* allocate and it should work fine:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void fit(char *string, size_t size);

int main(void)
{
    char string[] = "Hello People!!";

    fit(string, 6);

    printf("%s\n", string);

    return 0;
}

void fit(char *string, size_t size)
{
    if (strlen(string) > size)
        string[size] = '\0';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your are trying to cut a `string literal`, that is `const char *`, that is write protected.

You can change the code as:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void fit(char *str, unsigned int size);

int main(void)
{
    char test[] = "Hello People!!";

    fit(test, 6);
}

void fit(char *str,unsigned int size)
{
    if ( strlen(str) > size)
    {
        str[size] = '\0';
        printf("%s\n", str);
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Size passed greater than string length!\n");
    }
}
```

As you can see you are initializing an array of char (C-String) with literal string. So passing that array by reference (using [c](/questions/tagged/c) arrays *decay* to pointers when passed to a function) you can modify it and the result is what you expected.

A second solution is to create a new temp string inside the `fit` func:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void fit(char *str, size_t size);

int main(void)
{
    fit("Hello People!!", 6);
}

void fit(char *str, size_t size)
{
    // One char is added to store null terminator into new string
    char cutString[size+1] = {0};

    if ( strlen(str) > size)
    {
        for (size_t i=0; i<size; i++)
        {
            cutString[i] = str[i];
        }
        cutString[size] = '\0';

        printf("%s\n", cutString);
    }
    else
    {
       fprintf(stderr, "Size passed greater than string length!\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Your second solution prints garbage if a `size` larger than `strlen(str)` is passed.  It might be safer to initialize `cutString`.